# OmniStudio - Business Rules Engine - Decision Matrix - Number Range not working as per documentation

Tags: omnistudio

I'm trying to setup a Decision Matrix with 3 input columns (text, text, number range). As per the documentation mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.numeric_ranges_in_decision_matrices.htm&type=5), any value not present in the matrix as an actual row should be checked against the range and then a corresponding row returned based on which range it falls under. But even though the column is specified as Number Range, it still only works if it is an actual match to the row.

My matrix is as follows:

| Text1 | Text2 | NumberRange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | Bravo | 7 |
| Alpha | Bravo | 8 |
| Alpha | Bravo | 29 |

Based on the above table, the ranges, as per the documentation should be as below:

- 7 and below 7
- 8 to 28
- 29 and above

But the decision matrix only gives output if the third parameter is an exact match (7,8,29) but not any other number.

Has anyone else faced this issue? If Yes, how did you resolve it? Am I reading the documentation incorrectly?

**Note - I think this is a Salesforce limitation, we had inputs for multiple sets of data in the table and if 7 was the input to the table but the other columns did not match, the output was not desired, looks like we will have to maintain separate matrices for each grouping rather than have it all in one table**